# Error while passing an ArrayList to Service public method

Tags: android, service, arraylist, android-service

I am creating a music player app for android. I have a fragment in a ViewPager that displays a list of all songs on the device. I have implemented an onClick listener on the list item to start a service called PlayerService that will play the clicked music. However, I am getting a

```
NullPointerException
```

at the line

playerSrv.setList(songArray);

in the following code.

I can pass the songArray ArrayList to the listview adapter without any problem but when I try to pass it to the service, I get the error. Is there any reason why the songArray could be null? The service starts without any problem without the line that gives error.

The setList() method in the Service class is

```
public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs) {
    songs=theSongs; //where songs is a private variable of type ArrayList<Song>
}



public class AllSongsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Song> songArray;
    private ListView songListView;

    private PlayerService playerSrv;
    private Intent playIntent;
    private boolean serviceBound=false;
    //connect to the player service
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            ServiceBinder binder = (ServiceBinder)service;
            //get service
            playerSrv = binder.getService();
            serviceBound = true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } // onCreate()
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        songListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.all_songs_list);
        songArray = new ArrayList<Song>();
        getSongList();
        // Sort the songs
        Collections.sort(songArray, new Comparator<Song>() {
            public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
                // For case-insensitive sorting
                String a1 = a.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase();
                String b1 = b.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase();
                return a1.compareTo(b1);
            }
        });
        AllSongsAdapter songAdt = new AllSongsAdapter(getActivity(), songArray);
        songListView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        songListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(playIntent==null) {
                    playIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
                    getActivity().bindService(playIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    getActivity().startService(playIntent);
                }
                //pass list
                playerSrv.setList(songArray); //ERROR AT THIS LINE
                playerSrv.setSong(position);
                playerSrv.playSong();
            }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_songs_fragment_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    } //onCreateView()
    /*@Override
    public void onPause() {
        getActivity().stopService(playIntent);
        //playerSrv=null;
        super.onPause();
    }*/


    public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve song info
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, projection, null, null, null);
        // Iterate over the List
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get columns
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                String thisId = musicCursor.getString(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                if(thisArtist == null || thisArtist.equals(MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING)) {
                thisArtist = "Unknown Artist";
                }
                songArray.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }  while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        } // if
    } //getSongList()
} //AllSongsFragment
```

The service class is

```
public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private int songPosition;
    private final IBinder serviceBind = new ServiceBinder();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return serviceBind;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize position
        songPosition=0;
        //create player
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        initMusicPlayer();

    }
    public void initMusicPlayer() {
    //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs) {
        // Used to pass music list from music browser to the Player Service
        songs=theSongs;
    }
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }
    public void playSong() {
        //play a song
        player.reset();
        //get song
        Song currentSong = songs.get(songPosition);
        //get id
        long songId = Long.parseLong(currentSong.getId());
        //set uri
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, songId);
        try {
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("PLAYER SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
        }
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {      //start playback
        mp.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        mp.reset();
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }
    public void setSong(int songIndex) {
        songPosition=songIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that songArray is null?
It's possible that playerSrv isn't getting intialized.

Comment: @mt523 Sorry, I assumed that songArray might be null. The service starts without the error causing line and the two lines below it.

Comment: Yes. It seems playerSrv is not initialized. But how can that be? The it seems to be initialized in the ServiceConnection.

Comment: It would seem that way, but are you sure that onServiceConnected is firing before the onClick event that throws the exception?

Comment: @mt523 I think I have found the problem as mentioned in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7196345